# GitHub Dependabot fake alert - how to ged rid of it?

Tags: jquery, github, security, dependabot

My private repo has GitHub Dependabot alerts enabled. A few months ago, it detected XSS in jQuery, which has been updated to jquery-3.6.4.min.js which is not affected by this XSS.

Dependabot was silent for a few months, and nowadays, I receive alerts about an already-fixed issue.

[image]

Even if I click the link to **issue**, there is a 404 Error.

[image]

This is my actual repository, and I have just one branch.

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this apart from disabling Dependabot? :)

Comment: Is it perhaps still being referenced as an import somehwere? Have you done a repo wide search for something like `jquery-2.2.4.min.js`?

Comment: Nothing there; I'll disable Dependabot then. I don't see any other choice.